# windows 8 store FTP

Tags: vb.net, api, dll, ftp, windows-store-apps

I'm building a windows store application in VB.net, and when I try to get the certification, so I can publish it in the store, it fails the API test, because it doesn't accept the fact that I used AlexPilotti's FTPSClient dll.

The only thing I have to do is to upload a small video to the ftp server. Pretty simple, right? It's working properly, both in PC and Tablet, the only problem is the certification.

I had to use AlexPilotti's FTPSClient dll because "ftpwebrequest" is gone from Windows Store.

So, I wonder if there is anything else I can try, maybe a windows store compatible dll?

I have tried BackgroundTransfer, but apparently it only works with HTTP and HTTPS, not FTP.
I've been trying to find an answer for a few days now, but what I find never seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you need a Windows Store version of the library. I don't know free libraries with Windows Store support. Our SecureBlackbox includes FTP/FTPS components and has Windows Store assemblies, yet this is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this example by searching but didn't test it. Google is a programmers best friend.

```
Public Async Function FTP_Uploader(ftpURL As String, filename As String, username As String, password As String, UploadText As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
         Try
             Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftpURL + "/" + filename)
             request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Trim(), password.Trim())
             request.Method = "STOR"
             Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UploadText)
             Dim requestStream As Stream = Await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()
             Await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
             Await requestStream.FlushAsync()
             Return True
         Catch ex As Exception
             Return False
         End Try End Function
```